# Scroll to top of element in DOM - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I had this working in angular.js but I can't figure out how to convert it to Angular 8.  I need to locate the first 'iframe' in the DOM and scroll to the top of it on a button click that triggers this scrollToTop() function.

```
scrollToTop() {
    //need to scroll on body and html elements due to browser differences
    let editorBody = this.$document.find('iframe')[0].contentDocument.body;
    let editorHtml = this.$document.find('iframe')[0].contentDocument.documentElement;
    angular.element(editorBody).duScrollTop(0);
    angular.element(editorHtml).duScrollTop(0);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with vanilla JavaScript. You can use `querySelector()` to get the first Element which matches the specific selector (`iframe`). Then. you can use `scrollIntoView` to scroll to that specific position.

```
document.querySelector('iframe').scrollIntoView(true);
```

I have created a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/waterlooblue-scroll-to-top-hoz8go?file=app/app.component.html).